# Linear Programing of 16GB of data on 8GB of RAM

Tags: python, optimization, memory, scipy, linear-programming

I'm doing some linear optimization on a matrix that takes up 16GB of memory using the spicy.optimize.linprog method. However, my computer only has 8GB of RAM. I already consider the option of simply getting more RAM but besides that what other thing could I do to allow the program to still run.

Comment: Swap is a possibility (albeit it is slow) - what OS are you running?

Comment: I have access to both a Mac and a Windows computer @jrd1, also what is "Swap"?

Comment: Try this one for Windows: https://superuser.com/questions/793304/how-to-increase-swap-memory-in-windows . The Mac should do swap automatically. It is possible to modify it, though as indicated here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252429784

Comment: One last option could be creating a sparse matrix from your original matrix, and then using a different library for linear programming: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34821894/scipy-linear-programming-with-sparse-matrices

Comment: Thanks! @jrd1, I'll check them out

Comment: Also worth noting: An EC2 instance with 32G of RAM costs less than $0.40 an hour.

Comment: This is actually a really intriguing options @NickBailey

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use `scipy.sparse` to store the matrix. Almost all LP matrices are very sparse.