# How to deal with large arrays in python?

Tags: python, h5py

I have very large arrays which are needed to be stored on disk. How can I do that?
I tried using h5py, I read the documentation and found the issue with it is its 2nd dimension can have maximum number of 1024. How can I deal with an array that have dimensions of lets say 10^5 x 10^5?

Comment: So what you are really looking is a *multidimensional array*, right? Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1062629/742269

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you read [this part of the documentation](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/faq.html#appending-data-to-a-dataset).
This does not say that there is a *general* maximum size of 1024 for the second dimension. It's just an example of using resizable datasets.

The per-axis limit for HDF5 (and h5py) is 2^64 elements, as can be read in the documentationon on [resizable datasets](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#resizable-datasets).

Comment: what is meaning of "per axis limit of 2^64 elements"? @Hannes Ovren

Comment: It means that each dimension can have a size that is at most 2^64. That is a very very large number.

Comment: No. You can have approximately 10^19 rows if you want.

Comment: Yes. Every dimension actually.