# how to multiply large matrices without getting memory error

Tags: python, out-of-memory, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix `X` with `(140000, 28)` dims.
Calculating `np.transpose(X) * X` in python gives ***memory error***.
how can I do the multiplication ?

Name:X,  Type: Float64, Size:(140000L, 28L)... I think it is ndarray

Comment: How much memory do you have?

Comment: Is `X` a `np.matrix` or a `np.ndarray`? Can you show us actual code that produces the MemoryError? This shouldn't be a strenuous operation.

Comment: 16 GB on a good day

Comment: Any chance the matrix is sparse (is mostly zeros)? If so you can use numpy's sparse matrix stuff which might help a lot.

Comment: Is X (140000,28) or (140000,1)? If the latter is it a matrix or an array? I suspect the latter in which case you would be asking for a (140000,140000) array which is rather large. Try `@` instead of `*` or `.dot` on older Python

Comment: @PaulPanzer Sorry, it is (140000,28). So X.T * X dim is (28,28)

Comment: In that case it can't be ndarray because your multiplication would raise an exception. Please be careful in reporting these details because they do make a difference. If you type `type(X)` what do you get?

Comment: @PaulPanzer  `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: Ok, this is actually impossible, so please do me the favour  and type the following two lines `X.shape` if that does indeed return (140000,28) then please type your `X.T*X` again it should raise an exception complaining 'operands could not be broadcast together ...'

Comment: @user2357112 should I work with np.matrix or np.array in that case ?

Comment: @PaulPanzer yes you are right I did a mistake in the comment above, the code line is `np.transpose(X) * X` as written in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Very large matrices using Python and NumPy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053928/very-large-matrices-using-python-and-numpy)

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference. If your `X` is ndarray of shape (140000, 28) then `transpose(X) * X` will raise the same exception about incompatible shapes.

Comment: @PeterWood I don't think so, the matrices here aren't that large, really.

Comment: @MarounSassine: Never `np.matrix`. Always use arrays.

Comment: @user2357112 Seconded. MarounSassine did you try `transpose(X) * X` again with your confirmed ndarray confirmed (140000, 28) shape `X`? I'm not aware of any numpy version where that wouldn't result in a shape mismatch. Please try it and report back. Also your numpy and python versions would be useful.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I did this: 
    `X = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(X);`
    `Sb_t = X.T * X;`
for (140000,1) it worked, now I will try for (140000,28)