# Very large numpy array doesn't throw memory error. Where does it live?

Tags: python, numpy, memory, python-3.5

So I have the following numpy array:

```
X = np.zeros((1000000000, 3000), dtype=np.float32)
```

`X.nbytes` returns `12000000000000`, which is 12 TB.

I certainly don't have that much memory (8GB to be exact). How did this happen? Where is the array allocated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are using Mac. OSX will automatically use all available disk space as virtual memory. So maybe you have a biiiiiiig disk?

This code causes `MemoryError` on linux.

Comment: Ahhh. So it's an OS thing.

Answer (score 1):

I ran this on my Mac (OS 10.13, 16GB RAM, 512GB SSD) and had the same, successful results that you did.

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053928/very-large-matrices-using-python-and-numpy#comment9537062_1054079) seems like a possible answer. 
In summary: since you're using `zeros()`, there's no need to have each cell of the matrix take up 4 bytes when they all have the same value. Rather, behind the scenes, numpy may be explicitly storing in memory all values in the matrix that *are not* equal to a common value (in this case, zero).

Worth noting that running `np.random.rand(1000000000, 3000)` causes some havoc on my Mac, which does the same thing as `zeros()` but fills the matrix with actual data. RAM gets maxed out, then begins to use the swap partition.

Before `np.random.rand()`: 
[image: Before np.random]

During `np.random.rand()`: 
[image: During np.random]