# product of 2 csr matrices with correct shapes

Tags: scipy, linear-algebra

I am required to multiply 2 csr matrices with shapes A : (385019, 72) B :  (72, 385019). I do see that the # of columns of A is 72 and thats exactly the number of rows in B. Yet when I perform `sparse.csr_matrix(A).multiply(sparse.csr_matrix(A))` I get `ValueError: inconsistent shapes`
I have been through other posts but nothing has helped me yet. 
[Very large matrices using Python and NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053928/very-large-matrices-using-python-and-numpy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The multiplication you are looking for is called "dot product" and in python you can do that as follows

```
sparse.csr_matrix(A) * sparse.csr_matrix(B)
```

However, the multiplication that you are using `sparse.csr_matrix(A).multiply(sparse.csr_matrix(A))` in the problem you described is called "Point-wise multiplication by another matrix, vector, or scalar". This means that every element of A will be multiplied by every element of B if both A and B are matrices; in this case size of A and B must be same. If B is a scalar then every element of A will be multiplied by B.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mohsin :) That helped.

Comment: it was my pleasure to help