# How can a billions of computations be done without having memory error in python?

Tags: python, numpy, physics, differential-equations

I am trying to simulate a double pendulum sysytem by solving the necessary differential equation in python using numpy.

This is how my code looks like :

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as smp
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter
from sympy.physics.mechanics import dynamicsymbols, init_vprinting
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t, g = smp.symbols('t g')
m1, m2 = smp.symbols('m1 m2')
L1, L2 = smp.symbols('L1, L2')
the1, the2 = smp.symbols(r'\theta_1, \theta_2', cls=smp.Function)
the1 = the1(t)
the2 = the2(t)
the1_d = the1.diff(t)
the2_d = the2.diff(t)
the1_dd = the1_d.diff(t)
the2_dd = the2_d.diff(t)
x1 = L1*smp.sin(the1)
y1 = -L1*smp.cos(the1)
x2 = L1*smp.sin(the1)+L2*smp.sin(the2)
y2 = -L1*smp.cos(the1)-L2*smp.cos(the2)
# Kinetic
T1 = 1/2 * m1 * (smp.diff(x1, t)**2 + smp.diff(y1, t)**2)
T2 = 1/2 * m2 * (smp.diff(x2, t)**2 + smp.diff(y2, t)**2)
T = T1+T2
# Potential
V1 = m1*g*y1
V2 = m2*g*y2
V = V1 + V2
# Lagrangian
L = T-V
#using the  the euler-langragian
LE1 = smp.diff(L, the1) - smp.diff(smp.diff(L, the1_d), t).simplify()
LE2 = smp.diff(L, the2) - smp.diff(smp.diff(L, the2_d), t).simplify()


#now since we have two linear equations with two unknowns that is the second order s´dervative we can slve the equations 
sols = smp.solve([LE1, LE2], (the1_dd, the2_dd),
                simplify=False, rational=False)

#we have a symbolic expression above which can be converted into a numerical function provided that the values are given and the differential equations are defined
dz1dt_f = smp.lambdify((t,g,m1,m2,L1,L2,the1,the2,the1_d,the2_d), sols[the1_dd])
dz2dt_f = smp.lambdify((t,g,m1,m2,L1,L2,the1,the2,the1_d,the2_d), sols[the2_dd])
dthe1dt_f = smp.lambdify(the1_d, the1_d)
dthe2dt_f = smp.lambdify(the2_d, the2_d)


def dSdt(S, t, g, m1, m2, L1, L2):
    the1, z1, the2, z2 = S
    return [
        dthe1dt_f(z1),
        dz1dt_f(t, g, m1, m2, L1, L2, the1, the2, z1, z2),
        dthe2dt_f(z2),
        dz2dt_f(t, g, m1, m2, L1, L2, the1, the2, z1, z2),
    ]


t = np.linspace(0, 40000000,1000000001,dtype="float32" )
g = 9.81
m1 = 50
m2=25
L1 = 1
L2=1
ans = odeint(dSdt, y0=[1.57, 0, 1.57, 0], t=t, args=(g,m1,m2,L1,L2))
```

Now I use this code in jupyter notebook and when I execute the last part :

```
t = np.linspace(0, 40000000,1000000001,dtype="float32" )
g = 9.81
m1 = 50
m2=25
L1 = 1
L2=1
ans = odeint(dSdt, y0=[1.57, 0, 1.57, 0], t=t, args=(g,m1,m2,L1,L2))
```

I get this error :

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [19], line 7
      5 L1 = 1
      6 L2=1
----> 7 ans = odeint(dSdt, y0=[1.57, 0, 1.57, 0], t=t, args=(g,m1,m2,L1,L2))

File d:\python\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_odepack_py.py:241, in odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, full_output, ml, mu, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin, ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords, printmessg, tfirst)
    239 t = copy(t)
    240 y0 = copy(y0)
--> 241 output = _odepack.odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, ml, mu,
    242                          full_output, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin,
    243                          ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords,
    244                          int(bool(tfirst)))
    245 if output[-1] < 0:
    246     warning_msg = _msgs[output[-1]] + " Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information."

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 29.8 GiB for an array with shape (1000000001, 4) and data type float64
```

I did use float32 but it was not helpful. My project requires me to do the simulation of the double pendulum and then use the coordinates to create a probability density, so having a lot of points does help a lot with the simulations.

I want to have as many points as possible but was not able to figure out how this can be done.
Any kind of help would be really good :)-

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Very large matrices using Python and NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053928/very-large-matrices-using-python-and-numpy)

Comment: Seems like Scipy is converting the array to `float64` anyway somewhere in the package, so using `float32` won't reduce memory. 8 bytes per data, exactly 29.8 GB. This is one of the downsides with these algorithms, you are effectively brute forcing the solution hence it will take a lot of memory with a billion points.

Comment: Does this happen immediately after odeint is called? I tried this on my machine and it ran for about 10 minutes without error (and without any solution/output). I killed it after that time because I have no idea if the algorithm you've implemented is ever going to produce a result

Comment: Solve the equation in blocks, 1000 chunk of length 40000 for instance. Extract the statistics from each block, then use the last state as the initial state for the next block. With that you could even add some kind of progress bar or other progress reporting.

Comment: So evidently that large of a `t` isn't possibly.  Use a coarser one.

Answer (score 1):

A 64bit system may be able to map the array in numpy.memmap

But if the system is 32 bit then the maximum memory files reach 2 GiBso the 29.8GiB

Comment: the error occurs in a compiled function, `_odepack.odeint`.  You can't play with what it does.